# How to increase the value of a setting in 'Settings.json' with a hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode despite its many hotkey commands is still lacking some basic ones.

For example, its not possible to increase the terminals font size with a hotkey, the equivalent of `editor.action.fontZoomIn`/`editor.action.fontZoomOut` (increase font size in editor)

This settings exists already as `"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 12`. I am looking for a way to define two hotkeys that will let me increment and decrement the `12` value by modifying it in the `Settings.json` file.

I tried looking for an extension that could something like that, [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler) came close but after some experimenting I think it only offers a means of cycling  between `true`/`false` states, not incrementing numbers:

Is there a way to achieve this currently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!